# exiting vim without close tabs or files

Tags: command-line

I use `alias lvim='vim -c "normal '\''0"'` for reopen last files in my vim. But the questions is how exit `vim` without close any tabs or files, When I use `:wq` it close tab or files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you looking for [`:h views-sessions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#views-sessions) to preserve your views and open files?

Comment: Alternatively, `:suspend`ing vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code restores the exact state you were in on a newly opened vim (no arguments). That is if you remembered to exit vim using SQ(a newly defined key sequence). It also saves the files you were working on.

You might want to add this to your .vimrc:

```
nmap SQ <ESC>:mksession! ~/.vim/Session.vim<CR>:wqa<CR>

function! RestoreSession()
    if argc() == 0 && filereadable($HOME . '/.vim/Session.vim')  "vim called without arguments
        execute 'source ~/.vim/Session.vim'
    endif
endfunction


autocmd VimEnter * call RestoreSession()
```

Taken from here with a minor change 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/28614/gvim-configuration-does-not-work-like-it-should

I hope this is the answer you were looking for.